# $K\times X\rightarrow X$ Linear map?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-programming

From follands real analysis book:
The scalar multiplication is continuous from $K\times X\rightarrow X$ , where $X$ is NVS.
Now K(=R) is a vector space over itself, so  $K\times X$ is a normed vector space  Let $W: K\times X\rightarrow X$ be a map such that $M(c,x)=cx$
Outline of proof:
1.show M is a linear map
 2. Show M is bounded or continuous, then done.
I know this map is not linear, how to show mathematically that its not linear? 2 criteria: $M(cx)=cM(x) and M(x+y)=M(x)+M(y)$
I can finish the rest of the exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M$ is not linear but it is continuous: $c_n \to c$ and $ x_n \to x$ implies $\|c_nx_n-cx\| \leq |c_n|\|x_n-x\|+|c_n-c| \|x\| \to 0$ because $(c_n)$ is bounded.

$M$ is not linear because $M((1,x)+(1,x))=M(2,2x)=4x$ and $M(1,x)+M(1,x)=x+x=2x \neq 4x$ if $x \neq 0$.

Comment: where did you get $c_n\rightarrow c$and $x_n\rightarrow x$ from? Its not stated in the exercise, also can you show mathematically that M is not linear? I have to show its not linear not just state it.

Comment: @Alex I used the sequential definition of continuity. I have added a proof of  the fact that $M$ is not linear.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. I cant upvote yet since i am a new user, thank you!